# Why do psycopg2 writes take so long?

Tags: python, postgresql

I wrote a script that updates a table. Since I couldn't find a way to "batch" update, my script updates the table one row at a time. I assumed that for a set of 100,000 rows, it would take a few seconds to do the update.

No. Each write operation takes ~100 milliseconds. The entire write operation takes ((((100,000 * 100)/1000)/60)/60) = 2.77 hours. Why does it take so long to write?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import psycopg2
...
entries = get_all_entries()
conn = psycopg2.connect(params)
try:
    for entry in entries:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(UPDATE_QUERY.format(entry.field1, entry.field2))
        cursor.close()
finally:
    conn.close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can avoid making the transaction too big (which slows queries down) by running `conn.commit()` every few (2500?) queries… assuming you’re okay with not having the usual safeties of a single transaction.

Comment: One way to speedup it: upload your data into temporary table using [`copy_to()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from), then update your table by single SQL statement using, for example [`UPDATE ... FROM ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html).

Comment: @Abelisto interesting. can you post an answer with how you would do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
for entry in entries:
     cursor.execute(UPDATE_QUERY.format(entry.field1, entry.field2))

cursor.close()
```

You can profile this code with https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Comment: this isnt that much faster

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating table row by row from the client side you could to upload your data into server-side temporary table using [`copy_from()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) method and then update the table by single SQL.

Here is the artificial example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time, psycopg2
from random import random
from cStringIO import StringIO

CRowCount = 100000

conn = psycopg2.connect('')
conn.autocommit = False

print('Prepare playground...')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
    drop table if exists foo;
    create table foo(i int primary key, x float);
    insert into foo select i, 0 from generate_series(1,%s) as i;
""", (CRowCount,))
print('Done.')
cur.close();
conn.commit();

print('\nTest update row by row...')
tstart = time.time()
cur = conn.cursor()
for i in xrange(1,CRowCount+1):
    cur.execute('update foo set x = %s where i = %s', (random(), i));
conn.commit()
cur.close()
print('Done in %s s.' % (time.time() - tstart))

print('\nTest batch update...')
tstart = time.time()
cur = conn.cursor()
# Create temporary table to hold our data
cur.execute('create temp table t(i int, x float) on commit drop')
# Create and fill the buffer from which data will be uploaded
buf = StringIO()
for i in xrange(1,CRowCount+1):
    buf.write('%s\t%s\n' % (i, random()))
buf.seek(0)
# Upload data from the buffer to the temporary table
cur.copy_from(buf, 't')
# Update test table using data previously uploaded
cur.execute('update foo set x = t.x from t where foo.i = t.i')
cur.close();
conn.commit();
print('Done in %s s.' % (time.time() - tstart))
```

Output:

```
Prepare playground...
Done.

Test update row by row...
Done in 62.1189928055 s.

Test batch update...
Done in 3.95668387413 s.
```

As you can see the second way is about 20 times faster.

Comment: thanks! can you explain a bit about why this is faster?

Comment: @dopatraman Mostly because instead of executing 100,000 SQL statements you executes only 3.

Comment: can you explain these lines specifically? `cur.execute('create temp table t(i int, x float) on commit drop')
buf = StringIO()
for i in xrange(1,CRowCount+1):
    buf.write('%s\t%s\n' % (i, random()))
buf.seek(0)
cur.copy_from(buf, 't')`